# Update with inner join in compact SQL

Tags: sql

In access, I can use:

```
UPDATE Projects
  INNER JOIN (Images INNER JOIN ImageCrossRef
    ON Images.ImageId = ImageCrossRef.ImageId)
    ON Projects.ProjectID = ImageCrossRef.ProjectId
  SET Images.Folder = [Projects].[Folder];
```

to update a field in a table based upon two inner joins to another field, but this fails in Compact SQL. I've tried various suggestions with `WHERE EXISTS`, but none seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code isn't ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Are you trying to set the value based on the results of the inner join (i.e. set images.folder = (select *...)) or to do a "where" clause to decide which rows to update?

Answer (score 0):

You should "categorically" be aware that certain types of queries are not "directly updatable." This might well be one of them. Things which Microsoft Access is able to do, other engines might not. (And, SQL syntax which one server might accept, another one might not.)

One possibility which sometimes works is to use a "nested query" to provide the IDs of the records (`Images`) that are to be updated, and the values that should be inserted into them.

A second possibility is to use a "stored procedure," which is basically a small sub-program that is executed by the SQL server. The code in that procedure would do a `SELECT` as before, then iterate through that result-set issuing individual `UPDATE` statements in a loop.

I'm not familiar enough with *Compact* SQL to actually write a code-example for you, but I hope this at least gives you some options to think about. "HTH ..."